# In the NX OPEN C ++ library, is there an interface to divide the model into triangular patches?

Tags: c++, siemens, nomachine-nx

I am using the NX OPEN C ++ library, I need to divide the model in the PART file into small triangles, but I have not found the relevant API for many days. Does such an API exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API function / call directly, but, as a workaround you can perform a "STL Export", and then read the output file according to it's [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), it's pretty straightforward.

The STL export API calls must be named `UFStd.OpenBinaryStlFile` and `UFStd.PutSolidInStlFile` or somehow.